# A list of LEX expressions

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

Identify the lists of elements surrounded by <>, where elements can be : words formed with length multiply of 3 , even numbers with at least 3 digits .
The lists contain at least 2 elements separated by ',' .

Correct lists:<189,abc,abcdef,130057,11681111,abc>

Incorrect lists : <897,8999><00003,109,2000>

I tried to solve this problem , using :
word ([a-z][a-z][a-z])+ ;  number ([1-9][0-9])+[13579]

but almost all the time it recognize bots lists , correct and incorrect .

I don't know how not to show the list if I find one wrong element . Thanks !

Comment: Did you mean *odd* numbers with at least three digits?

Comment: Please show us a particular input that your code does not handle correctly, the actual output, and the desired output. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).